# UWP 10 - Windows App Certification Kit Failed Generating Report

Tags: c#, uwp, wack

[image: Windows App Certification Kit Failed Generating Report]

I try to uninstall the kit and download the latest WACK from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/app-certification-kit
still got this error. 
Could somebody help me resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please try to package an empty project to see if this error exists?And by the way, what's your OS version?

Comment: Hi thank you for reply, My winver 1709 (OS Build 16299.371). I try to create a blank UWP as you suggested and then try to create package then after run the WACK but still the issue of generating report still occurred. Any other suggestion that I can try to solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: Could you restart your PC or use another device to try this again? If possible, update your OS version and windows 10 SDK to 1803 and try again.